# Get Access Token During Admin Consent for Azure App

Tags: azure, access-token, multi-tenant

I have an App Registered in Azure Active Directory and Accounts in any organization can access the app (Multi-tenant).

I am using the following URL to request for Admin Consent.

**Request:**

https://login.microsoftonline.com/d1e71bad-1720-420d-81da-zzzzzzzzz/adminconsent?client_id=2073dd0f-e4f3-4c25-acbe-xxxxxxxxa&state=12345&redirect_uri=http://localhost:49573/Planner/Auth

When the user signs in and grants Admin consent, the response has values for Admin consent, TenantID and State.

**Response:**

http://localhost:49573/Planner/Auth?admin_consent=True&tenant=d1e71bad-1720-420d-81da-zzzzzzzzz&state=12345

Can I also get an access token in the Response during process of getting an Admin Consent

Thanks,
Gagan

Answer (score 0):

In one request this only is possible for User Consents, which you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) by sending the `prompt` parameter set to 'consent'.

What you need to do is chain events. The redirect URL you specify could for instance trigger a Delegated Authorization flow you need to get the job done. Be aware that this makes sense for Browser sessions, but for OAuth apps, it will not.